# WooCommerce - Conditional for page created by rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a page created by a plugin (Dokan) called Products: example.com/dashboard/products

The /dashboard/products page is created by a rewrite rule, it's not an actual page which can be seen in the admin panel. Therefore I can't use this conditional: is_page(page-id).

How else could I do a WordPress conditional to check the page is the /dashboard/products page?

This is the register_rule function code from the plugin:

```
$this->query_vars = apply_filters( 'dokan_query_var_filter', array(
    'products',
    'new-product',
    'orders',
    'withdraw',
    'settings',
    'edit-account'
) );

foreach ( $this->query_vars as $var ) {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( $var, EP_PAGES );
}
```

My end goal is to wrap these two lines in a conditional so they only run when on the `/dashboard/products` page:

```
add_action( 'dokan_dashboard_content_inside_before', 'custom_dashboard_menu', 10 );
add_action( 'dokan_dashboard_content_before', 'custom_dashboard_header', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, the request path, e.g. `path/to/something` as in `example.com/path/to/something?query=string&if=any`, is saved in `WP::$request` which is accessible via the global `$wp` variable, so in your case, you can do so to check if the page is `/dashboard/products`:

```php
global $wp;
// Note: No trailing slashes.
$is_my_page = ( 'dashboard/products' === $wp->request );

// Or without the "global $wp;"
$is_my_page = ( 'dashboard/products' === $GLOBALS['wp']->request );

// To check if you're on /dashboard/products/<anything>:
global $wp;
$is_my_page = preg_match( '#^dashboard/products/#', $wp->request );
```

And there might be a Dokan-specific way/API/function, but you will have to find that on your own.

### UPDATE

If `/dashboard/products` is not actually a registered WordPress rewrite rule, or that you're checking prior to WordPress parses the request URL, path, etc., then you can do "the PHP way" like so:

```php
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
    $path = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
    $is_my_page = ( '/dashboard/products/' === $path );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sally, great point and informative for future too. Unfortunately I am getting nothing when on /dashboard/products, I did a var_dump of the global $wp: `public 'request' => null` when on the products page.

Comment: I found a solution (probably not ideal but works): This global has `/dashboard/products/` - `$GLOBALS['_ENV']['REQUEST_URI']` I am now checking against that array item.

Comment: Actually, did you use the wrong hook? Because at least, you should use the `parse_request` hook to check the `$wp->request` - and if you use that hook, there's no need to `global $wp;` since the first parameter is indeed `$wp`.